# C++ - How do i make a form close the application?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

My Windows Form application has two forms. `Form1` and `Form2`. How to close entire application after the `Form2` is closed?

When I close `Form2` it only closes that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `Application::Exit();`

See the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: What my question is is, how do i make it exit the entire application when i close the form? Idk where the code for the red (x) button is.

Comment: @FreelanceCoder : Override your form class' `OnClosing` member function and call `Application::Exit()`.

Comment: @ildjarn Idk where the "OnClosing" function is.

Comment: @FreelanceCoder: You can add it in the designer under the thunder icon on the properties tab in MSVC. For more info and an example, RTFM here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @JanTuroň Thanks alot. I found it. Also thanks to ildjarn i got it to close. Thanks alot both of you. You're awesome. :)